# Cocoa: add/show NSBorderlessWindowMask window in window list

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've created a custom NSWindow which is borderless (Using NSBorderlessWindowMask style mask)

I want the window to be listed on the Window Menu (the list of windows shown when you right click on the app icon on the tray)

Note: Titled window with borders is automagically added to this list.

Do you know a way to solve this ?
Is it NSApp related thing ?

Comment: Do you mean the window menu or the dock menu?

Comment: Did you check if `NSApplication` has methods for dealing with the window menu? Maybe there is a clue like "Cocoa places an item in the Window menu automatically whenever you set the title of an NSWindow object.".

Comment: Very useful question and answer, don't know why it has been downvoted 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i found a way to add window to the window menu manually using NSApp.

`[NSApp addWindowsItem:window title:[window title] filename:NO];`